# For which $x \in \mathbb{R}$ does the series converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For which $x \in \mathbb{R}$ does the following series converge?

> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{n^3 + x^2}$

I am pretty sure this question is possible to solve, and I think all I have to do is get the top to equal the bottom to make it $\lt1$ right? Is this a good way to start?

Comment: For any $x$, $0\le e^{-x^2}/(n^3+x^2)\le 1/n^3$

Comment: @DavidMitra So I can pretty much just expand out that inequality to find $x$ then?

Comment: You can use it and the Comparison Test to show your series converges for any real number $x$.

Comment: @DavidMitra What about uniform convergence?

Comment: @Katie Why do you think that 'making it <1' implies the series converge? (If you believe so what is your take on $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x}{n}}$?)

Comment: I see your point @boywholived good call!

Answer (score 4):

The inequality 
$$0\leqslant \frac{e^{-x^2}}{n^3+x^2}\leqslant \frac 1{n^3}$$
valid for any integer $n$ and any real number $x$ together with the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}n^{-3}$ guarantees the normal convergence on the real line of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{n^3+x^2}$.

Comment: Does it converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes: normal convergence on a set implies the uniform convergence in this set.

Comment: Sorry what you have said states exactly what I asked. Thank you!

Edit: Yeah I realised that, along with noticing that $x^2$ can't be negative, meaning I can't make it any smaller via $x$.